# JaversException TYPE_NAME_NOT_FOUND: type name contains '$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$'

Tags: javers

Calling Javers.findChanges() results in the mentioned exception. It looks like my Pojo was somehow proxied or generated by CGLIB. Strange, because I am not using JPA/Hibernate but MongoDB. Two questions,

1. is there a way to prevent this in the future?
2. is there a way to "fix" the jv_snapshots table or extend Javers somehow to deserialize this Pojos correctly?

Thank your

Answer (score 0):

Your application should not commit CGLIB proxies to JaVers. When you are using JPA/Hibernate, JaVers automatically unproxies your entities (see https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#hibernate-unproxy-hook).

I don't know why your application generates those proxies, maybe some AOP framework? It doesn't happen in typical Spring configuration for Mongo.
It's not clear why you have jv_snapshots table since you said that you are using MongoDB.

Comment: OK, I think I am having proxies because I am using this mongo-Annotation:    @DBRef(lazy = true). Is there something like an unproxy hook for lazy dbrefs? I am having a jv_snapshots collection and another collection called jv_head_id. Is this wrong? Where should this things be stored in MongoDB?

Comment: If you have jv_snapshots collection (not table), that's fine :).

Comment: There are no automatic unproxy hook for Mongo DBRef, looks like a missing feature in JaVars, you are encouraged to contribute a PR.